# R: Find Matching Search Term in csv file

Tags: r, csv

I would like to know how to find the exact lower case string under the column Search Terms.

What I currently did:

Using  R studio, I read in a CSV file using this command:

```
books = read.csv("~/Desktop/R Class /BBbooklist.csv", sep=",",header= TRUE,na.strings = "?",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The csv file has a header:

```
[1] "Department"         "Search.Term"        "Search.Frequency"   "ASIN"              
[5] "X.1.Clicked.Title"  "Click.Share"        "Conversion.Share"   "ASIN.1"            
[9] "X.2.Clicked.Title"  "Click.Share.1"      "Conversion.Share.1" "ASIN.2"            
[13] "X.3.Clicked.Title"  "Click.Share.2"      "Conversion.Share.2"
```

Here is the image of the file called books:

[image: Snapshot of the CSV File]

What I want is to retrieve all rows for the search term: 'adult coloring books'
and save the rows to a new file called `keywords.csv`

I have tried several options like:

```
dta.subset<-subset(books,Search.Term = 'adult coloring books')
```

as well as grep commands like:

```
grep(pattern = "adult coloring books",x = string, value = T)
```

Comment: And what were the results of the methods you tried?

Comment: You need to read the tutorials on subsetting; there are [some good ones on the R tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info). Here, you likely need something like `books[books$Search.Term == 'adult coloring books', ]`.

Answer (score 0):

From OP's question, it isn't clear if the term can appear in any column or in one specific column. So I'll assume it can appear in any column, since this is more generic. But if the question is about one specific column, then my solution may yield wanted results depending on the data structure.

```
# dummy data frame 
set.seed(1) 
df = data.frame(matrix(sample(letters, size = 50, replace = T), nrow=10, ncol=5))
df
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1   g  f  y  m  v
2   j  e  f  p  q
3   o  r  q  m  u
4   x  j  d  e  o
5   f  u  g  v  n
6   x  m  k  r  u
7   y  s  a  u  a
8   r  z  j  c  m
9   q  j  w  s  t
10  b  u  i  k  s

# say we want all the rows for which there's "a" in at least one column
# vector of logic indexes, telling you which row has a letter "a"
x = apply(df, 1, function(x) {any(grepl(x, pattern = "a")) })

# what you want
df[x, ]
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
7  y  s  a  u  a
```

Now, if you don't need to match regular expressions, then this can be made even simpler:

```
ind = apply(df=="a", 1, function(x) any(x))
df[ind, ]
```

## Edit:

Now that the question was edited I realize that OP really should study subsetting in R, as someone suggested in the comments.

```
df[df$X3=="a", ]
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
7  y  s  a  u  a
```

Comment: Thank you the subsetting helped me to retrieve the correct entry. http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html

Comment: I will try to do the dataframe example as well. Some of the conversion metrics that I received need to be altered and I think this is better done using a dataframe.